# Какой атрибут более приоритетный в CSS атрибут ID или class?

Tags: css

Какой атрибут более приоритетный в CSS атрибут ID или class?

Comment: id [Идентификаторы и классы | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/identifikatory-i-klassy)

Comment: @greybutton Вам стоит написать ответ, прикрепив ссылку на оригинал

Answer (score 3):

**id** - идентификатор, может применяться для определения одного элемента (в основном используется, если к элементу применяется js). Идентификатор обозначают именем, которое следует за знаком решетки (`#`).

---

**class** - может использоваться для определения нескольких элементов. В CSS селектор класса обозначают именем, которое следует за точкой (`.`).

**По специфичности** (весу), наличие **id** в селекторе дает больший приоритет, нежели наличие класса!

Т.е.

```css
#my-id {color: red; }
.my-class {color: green; }
```

```html
<div class='my-class' id="my-id">Применятся стили id</div>
```

*p.s: если Вы об этом!*

Comment: Спасибо, да об этом